# .net 6 EF I want to make sure it doesn't create my view dbsets

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

**EDIT:** `modelBuilder.Entity<VwAlacaklar>().ToTable(nameof(VwAlacaklar), t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());` solved my problem.

I have a production in which I created a database in a new membership. There are 20 database view dbset classes in my partial dbcontext;

```
    public partial class DbModel
            {
                public virtual DbSet<ViewType1> ViewType1{ get; set; }
                public virtual DbSet<ViewType2> ViewType2{ get; set; }
                ...

                partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
                {
                   modelBuilder.Entity<ViewType1>(_ =>
                   {
                      _.HasNoKey();
                   });
                   modelBuilder.Entity<ViewType2>(_ =>
                   {
                       _.HasNoKey();
                   });
                }
            }
```

When I create the database with `Context.Database.EnsureCreated();`, Along with the tables, the views are also created like a table.

How do I prevent views from being created in the database? They just need to be in the project as code.

Comment: I'm gonna try this now @FranzGleichmann

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer :)